# Issues saving time upon app closing and updating UI when reopened. Swift

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to update a timer when the app is closed and then re opened, I know its a case of saving the time its closed, then calculating the difference between time closed and opened before adding it to the time count prior to it been closed, I have implemented the above code and for all the reviewing in the world I cant seem to figure out the issue.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

I have reviewed other similar problems but as of yet haven't found the solution, from my code I cant see where I sam going wrong .

Thanks again!

Josh

import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation
import GoogleMobileAds
import UserNotifications

class NewRunViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {

```
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
let regionInMeters : Double = 200
var seconds = 0
private var timer: Timer?
private var distance = Measurement(value: 0, unit: UnitLength.meters)
private var locationList: [CLLocation] = []
var polyLine: MKPolyline = MKPolyline()
var isCounting : Bool = false

@IBOutlet weak var MapView: MKMapView!
@IBOutlet weak var DistanceLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var PaceLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var TimeLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var StartButtonLabel: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var ResetButtonOutlet: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var StopPauseButtonLabel: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var bannerView4: GADBannerView!

@IBAction func StartButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
    isCounting = true
    ResetButtonOutlet.isHidden = true
    StopPauseButtonLabel.isHidden = false
    StartButtonLabel.isHidden = true
    updateDisplay(secondsForTime: seconds)
    startLocationUpdates()
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { _ in
      self.eachSecond()
    }
    

    if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedAlways {
        MapView.showsUserLocation = true
    }
    
    else if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedWhenInUse {
        MapView.showsUserLocation = true
    }
    
    else {
       let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Just to let you know...", message:
           "Your location services are not enabled, you can still use the timer but the distance and pace won't show without your location. You can enable location services in your device settings.", preferredStyle: .alert)
       alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .default))

       self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}


@IBAction func StopButtonLabel(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
    isCounting = false
    StopPauseButtonLabel.isHidden = true
    ResetButtonOutlet.isHidden = false
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    StartButtonLabel.isHidden = false
    timer?.invalidate()
}


@IBAction func ResetButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
    isCounting = false
    StartButtonLabel.isHidden = false
    seconds = 0
    distance = Measurement(value: 0, unit: UnitLength.meters)
    locationList.removeAll()
    timer?.invalidate()
    updateDisplay(secondsForTime: seconds)
    MapView.removeOverlays(MapView.overlays)
    UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "savedTime")
    UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "timeClosed")
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    checkLocationServices()
    timer?.invalidate()
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    StopPauseButtonLabel.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    
    bannerView4.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-6331942799423798/9472120281"
    bannerView4.rootViewController = self
    bannerView4.load(GADRequest())
    MapView.delegate = self
    
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(pauseWhenInBackground(noti:)), name: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)
    
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(willEnterForeground(noti:)), name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
```

//        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(pauseWhenInBackground(noti:)), name: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)
}

```
func setUpLocationManager() {
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
}

func centreViewOnUserLocation() {
    if let location = locationManager.location?.coordinate {
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion.init(center: location, latitudinalMeters: regionInMeters, longitudinalMeters: regionInMeters)
        MapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }
}

func checkLocationServices() {
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        setUpLocationManager()
        checkLocationAuthorisation()
    }
        
    else {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Just so you know...", message:
        "Sadly, your location services aren't enabled, change them in your settings to track your pace and distance.", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .default))

    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

func openSettings(alert: UIAlertAction!) {
    if let url = URL.init(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }
}

func checkLocationAuthorisation() {
    switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
        
    case.authorizedWhenInUse:
        
        MapView.showsUserLocation = true
        centreViewOnUserLocation()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Just to let you know...", message:
            "If you want to close the app or lock your phone while running, please go to device settings and enable 'Always' location", preferredStyle: .alert)
        
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .default))

        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Open Settings",
                                      style: UIAlertAction.Style.default,
                                      handler: openSettings))
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        break
        
    case.denied:
        
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Just to let you know...", message:
            "Your location services are not enabled, you can still run but without your distance and pace. If you change your mind later you can enable location services in your device settings.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .default))
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        break
    
    case.notDetermined:
        
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        break
        
    case.restricted:
        
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Just to let you know...", message:
            "Your location services are restricted, check your device settings.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .default))
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        break
        
    case.authorizedAlways:
        MapView.showsUserLocation = true
        centreViewOnUserLocation()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        
    @unknown default:
        break
    }
  }

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    guard let location = locations.last else { return }
    let centre = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion.init(center: centre, latitudinalMeters: regionInMeters, longitudinalMeters: regionInMeters)
    MapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    
      for newLocation in locations {
        let howRecent = newLocation.timestamp.timeIntervalSinceNow
        guard newLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 20 && abs(howRecent) < 10 else { continue }

        if let lastLocation = locationList.last {
          let delta = newLocation.distance(from: lastLocation)
          distance = distance + Measurement(value: delta, unit: UnitLength.meters)
          
          let coordinates = [lastLocation.coordinate, newLocation.coordinate]
          MapView.addOverlay(MKPolyline(coordinates: coordinates, count: 2))
          let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: newLocation.coordinate, latitudinalMeters: 200, longitudinalMeters: 200)
          MapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        }
          
          locationList.append(newLocation)
      }
}
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    checkLocationAuthorisation()
}

func eachSecond() {
  seconds += 1
  centreViewOnUserLocation()
    updateDisplay(secondsForTime : seconds)
}

@objc private func updateDisplay(secondsForTime : Int) {
  let formattedDistance = FormatDisplay.distance(distance)
  let formattedTime = FormatDisplay.time(secondsForTime)
  let formattedPace = FormatDisplay.pace(distance: distance,
                                         seconds: secondsForTime,
                                         outputUnit: UnitSpeed.minutesPerMile)
   
    DistanceLabel.text = "Distance:  \(formattedDistance)"
    TimeLabel.text = "Time:  \(formattedTime)"
    PaceLabel.text = "Pace:  \(formattedPace)"
}

private func startLocationUpdates() {
  locationManager.delegate = self
  locationManager.activityType = .fitness
  locationManager.distanceFilter = 10
  locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    centreViewOnUserLocation()
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
  guard let polyline = overlay as? MKPolyline else {
    return MKOverlayRenderer(overlay: overlay)
  }
  let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(polyline: polyline)
  renderer.strokeColor = .blue
  renderer.lineWidth = 3
  return renderer
}

@objc func pauseWhenInBackground(noti : Notification){
    
    if seconds == 0 {
        
    }
    
    else {
        
        UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "savedTime")
        UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "timeClosed")
        let shared = UserDefaults.standard
        shared.set(seconds, forKey: "savedTime")
        print(seconds)
        let timeClosed = Date()
        shared.set(timeClosed, forKey: "timeClosed")
        shared.set(isCounting, forKey: "isCounting")
        print(timeClosed)
        timer?.invalidate()
        updateDisplay(secondsForTime: 0)
    }
}

@objc func willEnterForeground(noti : Notification) {
    
    let isStillCounting = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isCounting")
    
    print(isStillCounting)
    
    if isStillCounting == true {

    if let savedDate = (UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "timeClosed") as? Date){
        print(savedDate)
        
    getTimeDiffernce(startDate: savedDate)
        
        timer?.invalidate()
        
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { _ in
      self.eachSecond()
    }
        
    startLocationUpdates()

    if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedAlways {
        MapView.showsUserLocation = true
    }

    else if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedWhenInUse {
        MapView.showsUserLocation = true
    }

    else {
       let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Just to let you know...", message:
           "Your location services are not enabled, you can still use the timer but the distance and pace won't show without your location. You can enable location services in your device settings.", preferredStyle: .alert)
       alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .default))

       self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
     }
    }
    else {}
 }
}

func getTimeDiffernce(startDate : Date) {
    let calender = Calendar.current
    let components = calender.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .second], from: startDate, to: Date())
    let diffHours = components.hour!
    let diffMins = components.minute!
    let diffSecs = components.second!
    let secsFromHours = diffHours % 3600
    let secsFromMins = diffMins % 60
    let savedSeconds = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "savedTime")
    seconds = secsFromHours + secsFromMins + diffSecs + savedSeconds
    print(seconds)
    updateDisplay(secondsForTime: seconds)
}
```

}